# Determining ArcGIS license server license is coming from?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager

I have a esri license server setup with a failover (as [described in the ArcGIS documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/license-manager/10.2/index.html#/Failover_license_servers/00790000000v000000/)).

All the ArcGIS clients have the environment variable `ARCGIS_LICENSE_FILE` set to `27001@mainlicenseserver;27001@failoverlicenseserver`.

Is there a way a can see from which license server a ArcGIS client (for instance ArcMap) got the license?

Comment: Don't you use ArcGIS Administrator to see what license server ArcMap is connected to? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: As far as I can see there is no way to see if you checked out a license from the main license server or your failover license server in the ArcGIS Administrator. You can see the currently available license from *one* server, that's all (As I understand it).

Comment: Ah, I see. You should probably update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command line tool *lmutil* on your license server machine to get these informations (a list of all client names).

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c your_license_file
```

If you have access to *lmutil.exe* at your client machine (it is only one file lmutil.exe) you can use it on client machine too:

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c 27000@your_server_host
```

Please note: The tool lists all client names. So it could violate privacy.

(I'm not sure if that works with 10.2)

Comment: ok, good to know, but the question if I - on the client - can see which license server that provided the license.

Answer (score 1):

JTB FlexReport LT is a free tool for viewing licensing for Flexnet products.

http://jtbworld.com/jtb-flexreport-lt

The examples on the page are for Autodesk products, but it works just as well for ESRI.  It uses the lmutil.exe function as described above, but has an easy to use interface and generates a neat report that will output to a web page.  You can even make it available to your users so they can run the report themselves at any time to see what licenses are tied up and by whom.